# Mockito doesn't intercept indirect method call?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have the following code snippet to simply represent the issue:

```
public class C2 {
    public String m1() {
        return "hello";
    }

    public String m2() {
        return this.m1();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C2 c2 = mock(C2.class);
        Mockito.when(c2.m1()).thenReturn("world");
        System.out.println(c2.m2()); -- mockito returned null instead of "world"
```

What I expect mockito to return is "world" instead of null. Is it I'm wrongly using the mockito API? if so, what's the correct way to achieve what I expect?

Answer (score 1):

Your object `c2` is mocked, actual invocation of the method `m2()` will not happen. Hence `null` is returned.

You will have to spy the class for your expected output. Spy does partial mocking. It invokes the actual methods while it still can be verified and stubbed.

```
C2 c2 = spy(new C2());
Mockito.doReturn(“world”).when(c2).m1();
System.out.println(c2.m2()); // this will return "world" as you expect
```

Comment: Keep in mind that when you use `spy`, if you call `when(c2.m1())` it actually calls `m1()` on the instance. This may have side effects. To prevent this, switch the order: `doReturn("world").when(c2).m1()`.

Comment: Noted and updated @RobSpoor

Answer (score 0):

The default return value for all methods on a mock is null (or the equivalent default values for primitive types). If you want `m2()` to return a value you will need to stub the call:

```
when(c2.m2()).thenReturn("world");
```

This is because the mock has *no implementation* for `m2` other than returning `null`.

Of course in a real test you would never call a method on a mock directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is a mocked class. You need to understand mock work as if it extending the class with overriding all methods. In youe case when you don't set behavior for mock methods it will return null by default.

Either mock the behavior of m2 method

```
when(c2.m2()).thenReturn("world")
```

or

```
 when(c2.m2()).thenCallRealMethod()
```